# Copy App Files and Install in a new domain using Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

After I create an app with App Maker, can I let someone copy that file and install it on a different Google Enterprise Account (i.e., a different domain).  The question assumes the Domain Administrator would want this and approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, you can easily export app as zip file on one domain and import it on other one. Just go to `Menu -> Export (.zip)`:

[image: Menu]

The story about data associated with app deployments is little bit different. You can read more about this topic in official App Maker documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export